# Memory leaks in my IPhone app

Tags: iphone, sdk

Potential leak of an object allocated on line 89 and stored into `imageView`

Some code:

```
NSUInteger i;
for (i = 0; i < kNumImages; i++)
{   
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"BackGround%i.png", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    CGRect rect = imageView.frame;
    rect.size.height = kScrollObjHeight;
    rect.size.width = kScrollObjWidth;
    imageView.frame = rect;
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
}
```

And I don't know what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[imageView release];
```

needs to happen inside that loop after the rest of the code.  Although you don't seem to be doing anything with it.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever object you "alloc" you should "release". In this case you have alloced UIImageView, but you have not called release on the object anywhere.

But, that aside what are you doing with the image view object you have created? In the code you have posted you have not used it anywhere. In case you are adding it another view, you can release the object after adding it to that view.